# Problem in an application written in VB 6

Tags: vb6, ocx

I am working on an application that written in VB6, and I have an error while opening one of its pages:

[image: The error that appears when i clicked on one of the application's pages]

Comment: Register the component 'DBLIST32.OCX'?

Comment: You need to install, reinstall or re-register the required component (Here DBList32.OCX) I think it is a component from MDAC. It might not be available on 64bits systems and or windows 10, I don't know.

Comment: Dblist32.ocx is part of the VB6 redistributable, not MDAC, although @VincentG could be correct that reinstalling the components might fix your issue.  VB6 SP6 rollup is documented and available here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/957924/description-of-the-cumulative-update-rollup-for-the-visual-basic-6-0-s

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- Search for this OCX file. Is it in `C:\Windows\System32` (or if you are on a 64b machine, `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`)?
- Try to (re-)register it with `C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32` (or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32` if 64b)
- If it doesn't work, **copy** the file on the current directory of the executable. (Although this last try shouldn't be relevant regarding the error message.)

Answer (score -1):

I think your system is 64 bit, re-install the vb6 and while installing time don't install in Program Files(x86). Instead of that install in Program Files, and if your operating system is windows 8 or above, while selecting the components un-select the DataAccess and install. After installation for visual basic give full permission to all users.

If you follow these steps then your problem will solved.